# What is .AspNetCore.Correlation.Oidc cookie

Tags: .net-core

What is `.AspNetCore.Correlation.Oidc` cookie and when it create. I seup up an `angularjs` client for `IdentityServer4` with `oidc-client-js` using `implicit flow` . It work fine but in some situations that not obviously for me there is may cookie items in the browser with this prefix:.AspNetCore.Correlation.Oidc.

```
.AspNetCore.Correlation.Oidc.....
.AspNetCore.Correlation.Oidc.....
.AspNetCore.Correlation.Oidc.....
```

and i get this error when browse the app:

```
Bad Request - Request Too Long
```

Anybody encountered with this issue?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue is when I call an authorized api from js client without signing or expired token.